# Display row twice if it meets both conditions within a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working off of Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I'm trying to get two rows out of USER_ID ST00825 as it meets 2 of the conditions within 1 case statement. Reading through other pages, it seems like I'm going in the wrong path and learning that case statements will only output 1 result but I'm not sure how else to do it. Logic below:

- If ConcatField contains numbers 8127 AND 22 AND Role = Configuration, then I need Violation column to be listed as 'Violates Points 8127/22'
- If ConcatField contains numbers 8127 AND 86 AND Role = Configuration, then I need Violation column to be listed as 'Violates Points 8127/86'
- In this case, USER_ID 'ST00825' meets both criteria's and I'm trying to get it to populate twice with the two violations. This is why I have "and USER_ID = 'ST00825' in the WHERE CLAUSE.

Any code suggestions would be appreciated.

Current code:

```
SELECT Z.*,

CASE WHEN
    ((ConcatField LIKE '%,8127,%' AND ConcatField LIKE '%,22,%') AND Role = 'Configuration') THEN 'Violates Points 8127/22'
    WHEN
    ((ConcatField LIKE '%,8127,%' AND ConcatField LIKE '%,86,%') AND Role = 'Configuration') THEN 'Violates Points 8127/86'
    ELSE 'No Violation'
    End As 'Violation'

FROM(

SELECT 
a.user_id,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + cast(SHARED_SECURITY_PT_ID as varchar(30))
            FROM [InternalAudit].[dbo].[SharedSecurity] as b 
            where b.security_class_id = a.SHARED_SEC_CL_ID
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS 'ConcatField',

    CASE WHEN
    USER_ID IN ('ST00217','ST00611','ST00805', 'ST00825') THEN 'Configuration'
    else NULL
    END AS 'Role'

FROM 
        clarity_emp a
    WHERE
        a.EMP_RECORD_TYPE_C in ('2','5')
        and a.USER_STATUS_C = '1'
        and USER_ID = 'ST00825'
) Z
```

Current output:

| USER_ID | ConcatField | Role | Violation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST00825 | 10, 8127, 22, 44, 86, 2, 1 | Configuration | Violates Points 8127/22 |

Expected output:

| USER_ID | ConcatField | Role | Violation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST00825 | 10, 8127, 22, 44, 86, 2, 1 | Configuration | Violates Points 8127/22 |
| ST00825 | 10, 8127, 22, 44, 86, 2, 1 | Configuration | Violates Points 8127/86 |

Comment: Please include sample table schema and data to go along with your desired results, refer to [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Note: `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check both violations as separate `SELECT` queries, connected with `UNION ALL` (there's some extra work around `NULL`/`No Violation` results, but this is the basic idea).

Otherwise, put them in a table you can you join with. You can do this on-the-fly with a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT Z.*, coalesce(v.Violation, 'No Violation') As Violation
FROM (
    SELECT a.user_id,
        STUFF(
          (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + cast(SHARED_SECURITY_PT_ID as varchar(30))
           FROM [InternalAudit].[dbo].[SharedSecurity] as b 
           WHERE b.security_class_id = a.SHARED_SEC_CL_ID
             FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
        ) AS 'ConcatField',

        CASE WHEN USER_ID IN ('ST00217','ST00611','ST00805', 'ST00825') THEN 'Configuration'
             ELSE NULL END AS 'Role'

    FROM clarity_emp a
    WHERE a.EMP_RECORD_TYPE_C in ('2','5')
        and a.USER_STATUS_C = '1'
        and USER_ID = 'ST00825'
) Z
LEFT JOIN (VALUES 
        ('%,8127,%', '%,22,%', 'Violates Points 8127/22'),
        ('%,8127,%', '%,86,%', 'Violates Points 8127/86')
    ) AS v(Match1, Match2, Violation)  
    ON Role = 'Configuration' 
       AND ConcatField LIKE Match1 AND ConcatField LIKE Match2
```

Comment: The example provided looks at 2 violations. In my actual example, I have to create a case for about 2000+ violation. Would this be the best way to do it?

Comment: @Meowzz updated the answer. For 2000+, rather than a values clause this should be an actual table, and even that assumes the match rules are consistent.

Comment: Really, though, I'd look to do the violation matching with the inner data, **BEFORE**  stuffing it all in a single field.

Comment: Question: The example looks at 1 role which is Configurations. In my actual example, I have about 200 roles to match on different violations pts. Say role3 is Supervisor and role4 is Manager. If a USER_ID contains points 1 & 2 & role = Supervisor, it "Violates Points 1/2". If USER_ID contains points 3 & 4 & role = Manager, it "Violates Points 3/4".  In your query, I see role = configuration which makes sense for the example I gave but I'm not sure how I would add more roles and points to this. Unless thats what you meant by matching violation with the inner data. Can you explain further?

Comment: Then it's another column for the Table Value Constructor or matching table you'll build.

Comment: And, again, if you can do this at the level of the inner data, before the STUFF call, the performance will be multiple orders of magnitude better: you won't have to use wildcard LIKE matching, or look inside of strings at all, and you can have indexes for the fields you need.